# Call Thinktecture IdentiyServer from android app

Tags: android, thinktecture-ident-server

I'm having a problem trying to call the identity server from an Android application. The problem is that I've searched for a way to call IdSrv from anything else other than a C# based app and only found an example of how to call it from JS. So, this is how the the call is made from JS:

```
function HttpBasicClient(uid, pwd) {
            this.scheme = "Basic";
            this.token = Base64.encode(uid + ":" + pwd);
        }
        HttpBasicClient.prototype.get = function (url) {
            var scheme = this.scheme;
            var token = this.token;
            var settings = {
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                    xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", scheme + " " + token);
                }
            };
```

And this is my translation into Android:

```
HttpClient client = getCustomHttpClient();
        HttpResponse response;
        String scheme = "Basic";
        String token = Base64.encodeToString((username+":"+password).getBytes(), 0);
        try{
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet("https://url/issue/wstrust/mixed/username");
            get.setHeader("Authorization", scheme + " " + token);
            response = client.execute(get);
            StatusLine sLine = response.getStatusLine();
            int statusCode = sLine.getStatusCode();
```

I'm using a custom HttpClient that accepts all types of certificates so the SSL shouldn't be a problem. The problem is that when the call is made an `Http 400`gets back to me which tells me that the request is malformed. My question is, does anyone know how exactly the call to the Identity Server should be made for it to accept it and return me the token?

Comment: Are you sure you want to call a WS-Trust endpoint?

Comment: Yes, I am sure. I've also looked at the traffic coming to the server (in wireshark). The requests that are coming from my client seem to be ok, but when the server tries to send back replies I always get Header checksum: 0x0000 with Message: Bad checksum.

Comment: WS-trust is a soap endpoint. And not get + authorization header.

Comment: I understand. Well that explains the 400 I got. In that case, would you be so kind as to provide a short example as how a call from Android should be made?

Comment: Why do you want to use WS-Trust. Why not an OAuth2 endpoint that is actually made for Http consumption? Check the Idsrv wiki on github for samples of that (look for resource owner flow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd rather want to use an OAuth2 endpoint - most probably using the resource owner flow. Check the wiki for samples:

https://github.com/thinktecture/Thinktecture.IdentityServer.v2/wiki

specifically:

http://leastprivilege.com/2012/11/01/oauth2-in-thinktecture-identityserver-v2-resource-owner-password-flow/

Comment: Well this might do the trick. But what if I don't have any OAuth2 endpoints configured? In the meta file of the Identity Server there are only WS-Trust endpoints. So if I am to call IdSrv with a WS-Trust endpoint I need to call it in a SOAP manner?